# Firebase email trigger extension: can't attach pdf file

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using the [firebase email trigger extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-send-email) to send an email with pdf attachment.
but mo matter what I do and how I send the file, I'm always get this error:

```
Unhandled error { 
   Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Property attachments contains an invalid nested entity. 
   note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient' 
}
```

I'm trying to send the pdf as text (or encoded text) and not upload the file to some storage and then just send the url.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/9f8d7fd6048bcaa7b5bc505cebe2e90494359e33/firestore-send-email/POSTINSTALL.md#message-field), the extension supports the following for the `message.attachments` property: "An array containing attachment(s); Nodemailer options supported: utf-8 string, custom content type, URL, encoded string, data URI, and pregenerated MIME node (be aware that your email has no access to the cloud server's file system)" Does your value meet these requirements? Can you show that in your question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the size of the file (more than 2mb of encoded content)